# creating logfile for a powershell script day wise

Tags: powershell, logfile

```
$dateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd" 

$Logfile = $logfile + $dateTime +".log"

if((Get-ChildItem $Logfile).CreationTime.Date -ne (Get-Date).Date)
 {
  Write-Host "creating new"
  New-Item -Path $Logfile -ItemType File -Force
 }
else
 {
  Write-Host "existing"
 }

 ## This function facilitates in capturing various events into a log file when the script          will run  
  
 function WriteLog
 {
   param([string]$Message)
   filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G) $_"}
   $Message = $Message | timestamp 
   Add-content $Logfile -value $Message
 }
```

I am using this small code which will create log file per day if doesn't exist. It append log messages whenever Writelog function is triggered.

Problem facing --> this is working as per expectations for maximum 4 consecutive runs and After this the script is running fine, but not appending any message to the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would define your log path variable once and then use throughout your script. You seem to be trying to access the same name by different methods which will be prone to errors. Your Write-Log method for example should take two parameters: Message and LogFile.
For an easier way to create logs using a Transcript, I have a logs sub folder and I just top and tail my script with the following:

```
# Start logging
#######################################################################
$log_path = $PSScriptRoot | Join-Path -ChildPath 'Logs' 
$script_name = $PSCommandPath -replace '^.*\\([^\\]+)\.ps1$', '$1'
$log_name = '{0}_{1:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.log' -f $script_name, (Get-Date)
$log = $log_path | Join-Path -ChildPath $log_name
Start-Transcript -Path $log -Append -IncludeInvocationHeader

# Do stuff
# Use Write-Host for log comments
# Captures errors without additional code

# Stop logging
#######################################################################
Stop-Transcript
```